# Should Feature Selection be Done Before or After Feature Scaling?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, normalization

I read feature selection should be done before scaling but did not find the source to be too reputable. Should Feature Selection be Done Before or After Feature Scaling? Why?

Comment: It really depends, some methods work better with scaled (normalized) features, others don't mind.